# Distributional derivative of a square integrable function and dual of Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

This is a simple question: Let $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $f'$ be its distributional derivative, then is $f'$an element of $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, the dual of Sobolev space $H^1(\mathbb{R})$? Also, if I take an element of $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$, say $q$, then is it true that there exists an element $Q\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $Q'=q$ in distributional sense? Why?

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna work with the fact that $H^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=(H^1(\mathbb{R}))^\star$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R})=H_0^1(\mathbb{R})$. By definition $$\langle f',\varphi\rangle=-\int_\mathbb{R} f\varphi',\ \forall\ \varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$$

Because $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $H_0^1$ we can conclude by the last integral and the Lebesgue theorem that for $v\in H_0^1$, $\langle f',v\rangle$ is well defined by the formula  $$\langle f',v\rangle=\lim\langle f',\varphi_n\rangle$$
where $\varphi_n\in C_c^\infty$ converges to $v$ in $H_0^1$. Thereofore, $f'$ defines a bounded linear functional, i.e. $f'\in H^{-1}$.

For your second question, take a look in [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) proposition 8.14.

Comment: Dear Tomas, for the second question, I've consulted Brezis's book, which, however, claims that $q=Q_1-Q'_2$, and $Q_1$ cannot be omitted unless the interval is a bounded one. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: @user52919, I think that's the only solution and is related with the Poincare's inequality. Try to look for a counter example for your estatement.